# Capitalization of number-noun-adjective

Tags: adjective, capitalization

Assume I want to use/create a german adjective of the form number-noun-adjective, for example think about things that are as long as two cars. Could I say

> zweiautoslang

or

> Zwei-Autos-lang?

In fact, if possible, I want to use the latter case, as my noun is a rather complicated scientific term. How do I capitalize such adjectives? Easy Example:

> Dieser LKW ist zwei-autos-lang / Zwei-Autos-lang / zwei-Autos-lang.

Comment: Just a hint: "zweiautoslang" reads like "zweiauto-slang". Also read [this article](http://canoo.net/blog/2014/03/25/das-fussballfeld-als-masseinheit/) on canoo's Blog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn’t any word composition happening here, as *zwei Autos* acts as a sort of adverb describing *lang* (I cannot exactly grammatically classify this right now). Therefore it is:

> Dieser LKW ist zwei Autos lang.

Also, compare to the following cases:

> Ich bin fünf Jahre alt.
>   Der LKW ist fünf Meter lang.